# Azure ML Pipeline fails while running a grid search CV on a cluster

Tags: python-3.x, azure, scikit-learn, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I implemented a gridsearchcv on Azure ML as a pipeline but I keep getting an error that says "User program failed with TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.

The exit codes of the workers are {SIGKILL(-9)}"

I tried changing the package versions but could not get it to work. The code runs well without error when I run it as a script but fails when I run it as a pipeline.

Any idea on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

This error `... excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker The exit codes of the workers are {SIGKILL(-9)}.`

Thank you [will kinsman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6179153/will-kinsman) and [pnmartinez](https://github.com/pnmartinez). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

This is caused by the `n_jobs = -1` which means parallelization in all CPUs (until last element of the array of cpus, hence -1).

You can try removing `n_jobs = -1` in `GridSearchCV` and put it inside `classifier` or try `n_jobs = 1` to deactivate the parallelization.

You can refer to [Memory leak using gridsearchcv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55886425/15969115) and [TerminatedWorkerError](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/skope-rules/issues/18#issuecomment-625893373)